# Comparing the database timestamp to the present time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a number of records in a MySQL database with one of the fields which tracks the time of the record creation. It is of the type 'timestamp' with the default set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I am trying to access all records that are newer than 5 minutes old. I have used the following query in a PHP page:

```
SELECT username FROM liveusers WHERE timejoined < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

For some reason, it doesn't select any records and I'm not sure how to rectify it. The PHP code is fine as it selects all records if I remove the condition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just use `timejoined > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` without the parentheses `)` at the end

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use  DATE_SUB:

```
SELECT username FROM liveusers WHERE timejoined > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp

You were doing the comparison the other way arround. Newer records should have a greater date than 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are comparing a timestamp against a date. You want to do first a conversion of the date, in example, using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

5 minutes is 300 seconds. Let's imagine someone joined at 50 and `NOW()` is 301 (it should be *"newer"*). `WHERE timejoined < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)` will become -> `WHERE 50 < 301 - 300` <- false

You want to write :

```
WHERE timejoined > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 4 MINUTE) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AS "is 4 minutes ago \"newer\" ?";

| is 4 minutes ago "newer" ? |
| -------------------------- |
| 1                          |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AS "is 6 minutes ago \"newer\" ?";

| is 6 minutes ago "newer" ? |
| -------------------------- |
| 0                          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/frNqYrK2SVkETDtN5zSt62/1)

Comment: `+ 0` will not correcly convert a datetime to a **real** unix timestamp see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/frNqYrK2SVkETDtN5zSt62/0)